# Global navigation is disappeared from a site

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Like the title says, Global navigation is disappeared from a site. SharePoint server publishing feature is active on both site level and site collection level. Can somebody help here?

Answer (score 0):

You may still need to update 'Global Navigation' option under 'Site setting > Navigation' for each subsite and Site collection after the feature is activated.

Note: The option selected for subsite and site collection could be opposite, to display the same navigation in all levels.
E.G. Site collection should have "Display the navigation items below.." whereas subsite shoul have "Display the same navigation items.." (with "Show subsites" selected for both)